# Is there a simple way to see what Bazel "Make" Variables are expanded to?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

Is there a tool for checking what variables in https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html will actually be expanded to? That can potentially help debugging and also understanding these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I later realized that these are expanded and logged to stdout during Bazel build.